# TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I cant figure out why

this.client is returning undefined when i try to access it from the OnDiscordReady() function.
The bot

The error messsage

```
/home/xcomegax/NCerberus/services/discordS.js:21
        Logger.log(`Discord client logged in as ${this.client.user.tag}`);
                                                              ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined
    at Client.OnDiscordReady (/home/xcomegax/NCerberus/services/discordS.js:21:63)
    at Client.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at WebSocketConnection.triggerReady (/home/xcomegax/NCerberus/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:125:17)
    at WebSocketConnection.checkIfReady (/home/xcomegax/NCerberus/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:141:61)
    at GuildCreateHandler.handle (/home/xcomegax/NCerberus/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/handlers/GuildCreate.js:13:31)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (/home/xcomegax/NCerberus/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/WebSocketPacketManager.js:105:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (/home/xcomegax/NCerberus/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (/home/xcomegax/NCerberus/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/xcomegax/NCerberus/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/home/xcomegax/NCerberus/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:789:20)
    at Receiver.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Receiver.dataMessage (/home/xcomegax/NCerberus/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:413:14)
    at Receiver.getData (/home/xcomegax/NCerberus/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:352:17)
    at Receiver.startLoop (/home/xcomegax/NCerberus/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:138:22)
    at Receiver._write (/home/xcomegax/NCerberus/node_modules/ws/lib/receiver.js:74:10)
```

The code i'm trying to fix debug >:

```js
const EventEmitter = require('events');
const Logger = require('./loggerS');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
require('dotenv').config();

class discordS extends EventEmitter{
 
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.client = new Discord.Client();
        this.client.on('ready',this.OnDiscordReady);
        this.client.on('message',this.OnDiscordMessage);
        this.client.login(process.env.DiscordAuthToken);
    }

    OnDiscordMessage(msg){
        if(msg.author == this.client.author) return;
    }

    OnDiscordReady(){
        Logger.log(`Discord client logged in as ${this.client.user.tag}`);
    }

}

module.exports = new discordS();
```

Everything seems to work except for my ability to access the this.client object.
The bot logs in then emits 'ready' then after that everything just doesn't work

I've tried using Object.assign(this, client : new Discord.Client()) in the constructor instead of just this.client =

but that didn't do anything to help.

What am i missing here?

Comment: Does it work if you define your `OnDiscordReady` method like this ? `OnDiscordReady = () => {`

Comment: your ``` this``` reference is not taking up the class's this.

Comment: @giuseppedeponte Yes it works when i use ()=>{ 

Is there anyway to fix the code without using arrow functions though?

Comment: @Raju I don't understand?

Comment: i explained in answer check that out brother

Comment: you can also use 
```this.client.on('ready',this.OnDiscordReady.bind(this));``` if you dont wanna use arrow function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class methods have their own `this` scope. that's why `this.client.user` is undefined , because this `this` is not class's `this`. to correct it  either you can `.bind(this)` inside the constructor for respective functions used or you can simply use arrow function to get the lexical `this` of the class itself

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');
const Logger = require('./loggerS');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
require('dotenv').config();

class discordS extends EventEmitter{

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.client = new Discord.Client();
        this.client.on('ready',this.OnDiscordReady);
        this.client.on('message',this.OnDiscordMessage);
        this.client.login(process.env.DiscordAuthToken);
    }

    OnDiscordMessage = (msg) => { //arrow function
        if(msg.author == this.client.author) return;
    }

    OnDiscordReady =() => { //arrow function
        Logger.log(`Discord client logged in as ${this.client.user.tag}`);
    }

}

module.exports = new discordS();
```

Comment: glad to help :)